# Can I ask about tools related to games?

Tags: discussion, steam

I've had a question on my mind for a while, but I've been reluctant to post as I didn't feel it would get a good reception.

It revolves around tools, tips, techniques and apps for helping to find a game to play. Quite often, I am struck with choice paralysis when looking at my Steam library, of 500+ games.

I would be interested to find out if anyone had tips, or even an application to help select a game to play. Such as asking a series of questions to help narrow down the choices.

The only tool that I know of currently, is the [SteamDB calculator](https://steamdb.info/calculator/76561197971413131/?cc=uk) which has a random game generator on it when you're logged in.

So would a question like this work for the site? As although your first thought is that it's primarily opinion based, an answer with an actual tool would be a perfect answer.

I have tried to create such a tool, but the lack of any decent web service provision by Valve makes things difficult.

Comment: Per the flags available on Arqade, it would likely be considered off topic, as the question technically contains a request/recommendation for software. Someone else could probably provide a more clear answer though.

Comment: Asking for tools that meet specific criteria still counts as a recommendation, I'm afraid.  You could try focusing on the fact you're trying to find another game to play, but I think that would either be too broad, or too opinionated to be useful.

Comment: Maybe if you ask something like : "How to choose the next game I am going to play?". Ask for a list of idea or technique to choose game, and says that you will give bonus point if the technique use a software. This way I don't think it count as a request of recommendation as the software recommendation is secondary. But, problem is that the question would probably still opinion based. An other problem is that there is certainly too much possible answer, the question is too broad.

Comment: Possible related post about game recommendations: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/q/997/108003. I don't agree with a lot of the things said there, personally, but much of the community's stance on recommendation questions is fairly well articulated.

Comment: Why not just use a random number generator?

Comment: @imulsion Because sometimes RNGesus simply will not agree with what kind of gameplay you are currently "feeling". If I had 750 games, and I wanted to play an action-based combat style game, there is a very high probability RNGesus would select a building simulation game, or something else completely wacky. And I don't know about you, but, I wouldn't want to wait for the game to load so I could close it to load a more suiting title.